Why sometimes the same kernel executes 10x slower?
Here's the code:
// default stream, 1000 blocks
cudaEventRecord(start1);
kernel_gpu<<<1000, dim3{32, 32, 1}>>>();
cudaEventRecord(stop1);

// stream1, 100 blocks
cudaEventRecord(start2, stream1);
kernel_gpu<<<100, dim3{32, 32, 1}, 0, stream1>>>();
cudaEventRecord(stop2, stream1);

// stream2, 1000 blocks
cudaEventRecord(start3, stream2);
kernel_gpu<<<1000, dim3{32, 32, 1}, 0, stream2>>>();
cudaEventRecord(stop3, stream2);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float t;

// first kernel time
cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, start1, stop1);
std::cout << t << std::endl;

// second kernel time
cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, start2, stop2);
std::cout << t << std::endl;

// third kernel time
cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, start3, stop3);
std::cout << t << std::endl;

// start time of the second kernel relative to the first
cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, start1, start2);
std::cout << t << std::endl;

// start time of the second kernel relative to the first
cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, start1, start3);
std::cout << t << std::endl << std::endl;

It runs the same kernel 3 times, multiple frames. The second kernel has a reduces number of blocks.
After the synchronization I'm measuring the following times:

execution time of the 1st kernel
execution time of the 2nd kernel
execution time of the 3rd kernel
relative start of the second kernel
relative start of the third kernel

The results are different from frame to frame, but it converges to 2 patterns:
25.1095
3.23891
25.8181
25.1116
25.1136

and
23.074
27.5548
26.0465
23.0779
23.0758

or graphically:

There are 2 questions:

Why sometimes the second kernel, which has 10x less work than other two, executes longer?
Why both  the second and the third kernels start exactly after the first ends? Not one after another sequentially, not all 3 overlapped.


This happens because the second and third launches were using different (non-default) streams. This tells the CUDA runtime that they are independent and it is up to the runtime to schedule blocks from the two grids in whatever order it wants (up to stream priorities*). This feature allows running multiple grids concurrently to get higher GPU utilization during small grids or to hide the tail effect. If one wants two grids to run sequentially, one either needs to launch them on the same stream or one needs to synchronize the two streams using an event.
There is no overlap between these two grids and the first grid because the first launch is using the default stream and therefore the host waits for its completion before launching the other grids. When using a non-default stream, launches are asynchronous with respect to the host, i.e. the host doesn't wait for the second grid to complete before launching the third which answers question 2.
Regarding question 1, I guess that the smaller grid sometimes seems to execute for longer because the runtime "randomly" decided to start running blocks from the third launch before continuing with the second one. It looks like the total runtime stays the same though.
These confusing timings are the reason why one should not use events for fine-grained benchmarking with multiple independent streams. When multiple kernels run in parallel on different streams the time measurements for single launches will lose their meaningfulness. As OP seems to have found out as well, a trace from e.g. Nsight Systems is a better tool for getting an overview of what is happening when and for how long than events in such a case.
When optimizing single kernels instead of the looking at the bigger picture of their interplay in an application, I would recommend using nvbench. It will take care of benchmarking best-practices like not benchmarking on multiple streams.

*: For completeness: The programmer has some power over which stream is prioritized for scheduling blocks by assigning stream priorities. But that does not necessarily help with the benchmarking problem at hand especially due to the priorities only being a hint to the runtime. The runtime will not cancel or pause blocks that are already running to schedule blocks from a higher priority stream. Giving the stream of the small second grid a higher priority than the stream of the big third one could however give more consistent timing results with the expected shorter runtime of the smaller grid.

Oh, I was not aware that NULL stream has a special meaning. I was sure that just having different streams is enough to try to run kernels in parallel.
